# Does HP LaserJet firmware update remove functionality?

Tags: printer, firmware, hp-laserjet

I just got an old LaserJet 2400 series, retired from business use. Is there any reason NOT to update the 10 year old firmware? For example, is there a substantial chance of bricking the printer? Or even worse, does newer firmware include obnoxious DRM that blocks 3rd party toner cartridges?

Comment: You should only upgrade firmware unless you have a reason.  This is true for any device.  If something is not working upgrade it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the firmware should not remove any functionality, but there is always a possibility that something may go wrong during the update process. That will most likely leave you with a dead printer.

On the other hand, as Ramhound said, updates should **only** be done if you have a valid reason. Unless the upgrade will fix a bug that affects you, or if it offers some new functionality that you want to use, there really is no reason for the upgrade. With an old printer I am sure there is no additional functionality, so that only leaves bugs.

Conclusion: if the printer has been working fine, leave it as is.

Even if the printer has been giving problems, make sure you first reset it to factory default settings, before you even think of an upgrade. Factory resets solve many, many printer problems by clearing all the data that's stored in the printer's non-volatile memory. [HP's support website](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-LaserJet/Reset-HP2430n-to-factory-defaults/td-p/1069680#.U4Kbks61Xj5) gives instructions for it (they call it a "cold reset"). If the following does not work, check out the variations given in the link.

1. Turn the printer off.
2. Hold down the select button and turn the printer on. Hold down the select button until all three printer control-panel lights flash once and then remain on. This might take up to 10 seconds.
3. After the message SELECT LANGUAGE appears on the display, press the Up Arrow button or the Down Arrow button until COLD RESET is highlighted.
4. Press the Select button. The printer performs a cold reset and then continues its power-on sequence.